# print dictionary key in new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

[Here is a sample of the data my macros work on.](http://www.filedropper.com/dotcountingpp1)

The following code uses a dictionary object to count button presses and then AOI entries, and then print the counts to other columns on the same worksheet:

```
Dim dBT As Object 'global dictionary

Sub buttonpresscount()

    'constants for column positions
    Const COL_BLOCK As Long = 1
    Const COL_TRIAL As Long = 2
    Const COL_ACT As Long = 7
    Const COL_AOI As Long = 8

    Dim rng As Range, lastrow As Long, sht As Worksheet
    Dim d, r As Long, k, resBT()

    Set sht = Worksheets("full test")
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dBT = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rng = sht.Range("B7:I" & lastrow)

    d = rng.Value  'get the data into an array

    ReDim resBT(1 To UBound(d), 1 To 1) 'resize the array which will
                                        '  be placed in ColT

    'get unique combinations of Block and Trial and pressedcounts for each
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_ACT) <> "", 1, 0)
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r

    'place array to sheet
    sht.Range("T7").Resize(UBound(resBT, 1), 1) = resBT

    'clear dictionary
    dBT.RemoveAll

'count AOI entries
 For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r

    'place array to sheet
    sht.Range("U7").Resize(UBound(resBT, 1), 1) = resBT

End Sub
```

I now want the "count AOI entries" bit of the code to print to designated cells in a new sheet that is created with this code:

```
Sub createsummarytable()
'add new worksheet to data
Dim datasummary As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
.Name = "datasummary"

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim t As Long
Dim Startrow As Long

Startrow = -4
t = 1

'print Block number headings
For i = 1 To 40
    If i < 31 Then
    .Cells(Startrow + (5 * i), 1).Value = "Block " & i

    Else     'print transfer block headings

    .Cells(Startrow + (5 * i), 1).Value = "Transfer Block " & t
    t = t + 1
    End If

 'print trial number headings
    For j = 1 To 18
    .Cells((Startrow + 1) + (5 * i), j).Value = "Trial, " & j
    Next j
Next i

End With
End Sub
```

I know that the code for formatting the table in the new sheet is rough, and ideally would be incorporated into the first module of code. I will look into that in future.

[image: Here is a screenshot of what the table in the new sheet looks like]

I want the AOI entries count to go into the first row below trials, but have no idea how to separate out the counts for each trial and block into different rows and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'....
'clear dictionary
dBT.RemoveAll

'count AOI entries
For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
    k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
    dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)
Next r

createsummarytable

PopSummary dBT
```

Sub to populate the summary sheet (likely needs some checks for "not found" cases...)

```
Sub PopSummary(dict)

    Dim sht As Worksheet, k, b, t, f, f2

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("datasummary")

    For Each k In dict

        b = Split(k, "|")(0) 'get block
        t = Split(k, "|")(1) 'get trial
        'find the block
        Set f = sht.Columns(1).Find(what:=b, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            'find the trial under that block
            Set f2 = f.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Find(what:=t, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not f2 Is Nothing Then f2.Offset(1, 0).Value = dict(k)
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: That works brilliantly Tim, thanks again. Stay tuned for my next tasks, where I'll need to print the RTs in the row below, and also average the trials ;)